# Disable connectivity check

Tags: networking, network-manager

I am trying to connect to a network using cellular with restricted access on cellular but device keeps connecting to unristricted Wi-Fi connection.

I have setup the network manager configuration to below:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[connection]
ipv4.route-metric=1000

[connection-cellular]
match-device=interface-name:wwan0
ipv4.route-metric=100


[connection-wifi]
[match-device=interface-name:wlp4s0]
[ipv4.route-metric=500]

[connection-ethernet]
match-device=interface-name:enp3s0
ipv4.route-metric=2000
```

- Ethernet is connected to a device which does not have internet.
- Wifi has unrestricted internet access.
- Cellular has restricted internet access.

Network connectivity is set to disabled using the UI and also in the below location:

```
/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf 
[connectivity]
[uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com/]
```

I would like to connect using cellular not Wi-Fi. But for some reason the OS keeps connecting to Wifi. Although cellular does come online for short time.

It looks like that although the connectivity checking is off, but it still tries to connect on cellular first and because cellular has restricted access then it falls onto Wi-Fi.

[connectivity]
.set.enabled=false

How can I disable the connectivity checking and get the device to connect to cellular even though there is restricted internet access on cellular?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS